# How to add as attribute and get React Konva Element ID

Tags: reactjs, react-konva

I would like to know how to add an ID to an element and retrieve it similarly to `e.target.getAttribute("id")` for DOM elements. One thing to note is that the elements are based on an array that is part of the parent component. In order for the elements to render based on the parent's array, I added the and at parent component while and are at the child's. In short, it is structured this way.

Parent Class:

```
<div class="designScreen" onMouseDown={this.activateRouteTrigger} onMouseUp={this.deactivateRouteTrigger} onMouseMove={this.updateRoutePosition} >

<Stage
width={900}
height={700}>
<Layer>


{
                  this.state.trends.map((el) => {
                    return <Content id={el.id}
                                    element={el.element}
                                    color={el.color}
                                    title={el.title}
                                    type={el.type}
                                    visibilityStatus={el.visibilityStatus}
                                    selectType={this.selectType}
                                    parentCallback = {this.selectDestinations}
                                    selectedDestinationID = {this.state.selectedDestinationID}
                                    destinations={this.state.destinations}
                                    parentCallbackColor = {this.changeColorSelector}
                                    timerString={this.state.timerString}


                    /> 

                  })
              }  





</Layer>
</Stage>
</div>
```

Child Class:

```
render(){
const ex1=    <Group >
   <Rect name="name" onClick={this.selectedRouteID} width={10} height={10} draggable={true} fill="green"></Rect>
<Arrow  id={`${this.props.element} content`}  onClick={this.selectedRouteID} points={[700,300,200,300]} pointerLength={20} zIndex={5} draggable="true"
pointerWidth={20} fill={`${this.props.color}`} stroke={`${this.props.color}`}  strokeWidth={4} />

</Group>

const ex2= 
<Arrow points={[100,300,600,300]} pointerLength={20} zIndex={5} draggable="true"
pointerWidth={20} fill={`${this.props.color}`} stroke={`${this.props.color}`}  strokeWidth={4} />



        return(

            this.props.element==="line" ? ex1 : ex2




        )
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, use `e.target.getAttrs().fill`, to get fill and replace it for other attributes